# Trigger.io: IOS7 Applied Filter Image feature not applied using forge.file Module

Tags: ios, camera, trigger.io

We are using the Camera and Gallery Functionality of trigger.io. We are using forge.file Function in getting and capturing image.

When we apply filters to the image, and when we are now going to display the picture with applied filters, it displays the original file without any filters applied.

Can someone confirm this to us??

Screenshots: [image]

But when we displayed by using `forge.file.getImage()`, the applid filter was not applied to the image

[image]

Comment: Might be a stupid questions, but are you saving the image with the filter before you try and pull it from the file system? 

Maybe post some code too, that can help

Comment: Image are saved and filters were already applied. Even when you get an image were a filter was applied, what it display is just the normal image

Comment: Can someone from trigger.io answer the question? It seems trigger.io been inactive for this past month...